# How to go about creating an ASP.Net Core GraphQL server backed by Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, graphql

I have been following the [graphql-dotnet](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet) and [graphql-net](https://github.com/ckimes89/graphql-net) projects with great interest...but it is not clear what steps/packages would one need to employ to have a fully functioning graphql server in ASP.Net core backed by EF Core. Any pointers or suggestions will be most helpful. Even a simple example of Posts, Authors will be a great, as I am struggling to find any documentation on this subject.

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/JacekKosciesza/StarWars

Comment: New on this topic are this  https://github.com/JuergenGutsch/graphql-aspnetcore and this  https://github.com/ckimes89/graphql-net

Comment: Here's a recent guide using that exact stack to build a GraphQL service: https://fullstackmark.com/post/17/building-a-graphql-api-with-aspnet-core-2-and-entity-framework-core